# Aplicación Android Rechazada

Tags: android, webview, google-play

APLICACIÓN RECHAZADA

La aplicación que has enviado recientemente se ha rechazado por infringir la Política de Uso Inadecuado del Dispositivo y de la Red. Antes de enviar tu aplicación para otra revisión, lee la política y modifica la aplicación para garantizar que no habilite la reproducción en segundo plano de vídeos de YouTube. Si has enviado una actualización, la versión anterior sigue estando disponible en Google Play.

**Publique mi aplicación y de acuerdo a este mensaje se que en un webview cargo un canal de youtube, que puedo hacer para publicar mi app sin ser rechazada?**

Answer (score 1):

Para ganar dinero tienes varias opciones

- Agregar los Ads de google oficiales https://developers.google.com/ads/
- Crear una versión de paga de tu App
- Conseguir sponsors(patrocinadores) que te paguen por agregar "menciones"(NO BANNERS).
- Botón de donar (aun que no es seguro que lo hagan y si eres muy persistente menos)

En cuanto a la reproducción en segundo plano esta encontrar de su política y punto, si quieres que la aprueben , lo que puedes hacer es crear un botón que abra la App de youtube. Es fácil detectar que apps están usando servicios en segundo plano, así que ahorrate tiempo intentando "trucos".

Comment: Entiendo que la pregunta principal se refiere a publicar la app.

Answer (score -1):

La versión anterior aún esta publicada pero la nueva tiene ciertas características que impiden sean subida, ya sea por un rating incorrecto, código malicioso, etc...

en este caso el problema es  "modifica la aplicación para garantizar que no habilite la reproducción en segundo plano de vídeos de YouTube", desconozco porque esto no es permitido, ya que anteriormente únicamente se podría realizar si el dispositivo tenía permisos ROOT, si agregaste esta funcionalidad seguramente tendrás que quitarla de tu aplicación.